How to add multiple object list to same attribute in openAPI?
I am using OpenApi 3.0.1 to generate my model objects.
below are two sample response
{
    "data": [
    {
     "CarList": [
      {
       "cardId": "carId"
      }
     ]
    }
  ]
}

And
{
    "data": [
    {
     "BikeList": [
      {
       "bikeId": "bikeId"
      }
     ]
    }
  ]
}

i want to create a model class Data with an attribute which can be used while setting the list
public class Data{
private List<Object> vehicleList;

I have tried to create Data schema in both response but first one being overwritten by second. So my Data model class is looking like this
public class Data{
private List<Bike> bikeList;


Give me some more context, are you planning to use Data in 2 different api's?

yes, there are two apis /Vehicle/Cars and /Vehicle/Bikes.

have you figure out the issue if not please add your controller and Pojo classes in the question
